# NHibernate Statistics Queries not visible

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am trying to use the nHibernate IStatistics for my app. I have some code like this

```
IStatistics stats = GetSessionFactory().Statistics;
var queryCount = stats.QueryExecutionCount; 
var queries = stats.Queries;
```

The queryCount is populated with a value for the number of queries but the queries string array is always empty. Is there a reason for this? I am using NHibernate 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this before running any queries:

```
stats.IsStatisticsEnabled = true;
```

After doing that, the following code:

```
session.CreateQuery("from Foo").List();
Console.WriteLine(stats.Queries[0]);
```

...will print "from Foo".

Only HQL Queries are stored (also LINQ, but just the string is not very useful)

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't appear to work. The Queries list in the IStatisics is still not populated. The other stats appear to be working.

Comment: @Craig: It works fine for me, I just tested it (see added example). What version are you using? What's your query? This property only includes HQL and LINQ.

Comment: That could be the problem then, I am using ICriteria.

Comment: Add to your answer that Queries is only populated by HQL and Linq (old version) and I will mark as correct.